# What is the point of the Error Message Correlation ID in Sharepoint 2010

Tags: 2010

This might sound noob but it's pretty annoying. Instead of receiving a nice error message, SharePoint 2010 throws you a page saying that there is an error and it gives you a Correlation ID.

WTF is a Correlation ID. What can I do to find out the exact error that actually occurred?

It seems like we've returned to the good old win98 days where the error was 0x80002330.

Answer (score 14, accepted):

You can use the ULS logs in the 14-hive/logs, and search for the correlation ID. You will then get all messages related to that correlation ID. You can either look through the text file, or use the [ULS Viewer](http://ulsviewer.codeplex.com/).

Alternatively, you can execute e.g. this Powershell command to get the messages with this correlation id:

```
Get-SPLogEvent | ?{$_.Correlation -eq "YOUR-CORRELATION-ID-HERE"} |
ft Category, Message -Autosize
```

Comment: One caveat to this method is that it will peg resources to the max.  On our prod server this took us to 99% utilization, and we had to cancel the query after 5 minutes, no result yet.

Comment: Also, for us newbies who don't have the 14-hive location memorized, it's: C:\Program Files\Common Files\Microsoft Shared\Web Server Extensions\14\LOGS

Comment: Tom; Yes, that's definitively something to be vary of. You can limit the search interval by time though, by adding starttime and endtime parameters, example: Get-SPLogEvent -StartTime "12/04/2007 17:00" -EndTime "12/04/2007 18:00" (http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ff607589.aspx)

Answer (score 3):

The correlation ID is the unique identifier for the request, not for the error itself.

In simple cases, it can be used to quickly search the logs to get a more detailed error message (e.g with a stack trace) than what was shown to the user. You can either search the trace log files or the logging database with that correlation ID and you'll get every log message related to that request. In more complex cases, the error might have been caused by something that happened earlier in the page's life cycle, so being able to narrow your search will get you the information you need faster.

The correlation ID is written to the end of each line in the trace log files, which are by default stored in `C:\Program Files\Common Files\Microsoft Shared\Web Server Extensions\14\LOGS`like Tom Halladay said. Alternatively, you can search the `WSS_UsageApplication` database's `ULSTraceLog` view, which has a separate field for the correlation ID.

Answer (score 0):

You can use SharePoint 2010 Management Shell and use this command to read error behind correlation ID

```
get-splogevent | ?{$_.Correlation -eq "CORRELATION ID"} | select Area, Category, Level, EventID, Message |Format-List
```

Read more [How to find real error in Sharepoint 2010 based on Correlation ID of the error](http://ittechnotebook.blogspot.com/2013/07/how-to-find-real-error-in-sharepoint.html)

Answer (score 0):

If you have a multi-server farm, a correlation ID or other parameters can be used to correctly merge the logs from every server into one file using the Merge-SPLogFile cmdlet, which I highly recommend.

Answer (score 0):

There are 2 ways to find the solutions:

1. Run the `Get-SPLogEvent` Windows Powershell cmdlet:

   `Get-SPLogEvent | ?{$_.Correlation -eq "Correlation ID"} | ft Category, Message -Autosize`
2. View the ULS (Unified Logging Service)

   This is a tab on the Developer Dashboard.

Answer (score -2):

You can execute query shown below inside your SharePoint database.

> select   [RowCreatedTime], 
>   [ProcessName],  [Area],
>         [Category],  EventID,  [Message]
>   from 
>   [WSS_UsageApplication].[dbo].[ULSTraceLog]  where  CorrelationId=
>   'B4BBAC41-27C7-4B3A-AE33-4192B6C1E2C5'

You can find more details available [here](http://www.zimmergren.net/archive/2010/09/03/sp-2010-find-error-messages-with-a-correlation-id-token-in-sharepoint-2010.aspx)

Comment: Don't do this, please!

Comment: I strongly suggest you never even think about thinking about opening the SharePoint database

Comment: SharePoint's Usage and Logging database is supported for querying and building custom views. Please read carefully before downvoting. http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/jj715694(v=office.14).aspx

Comment: By the way, this database also depends on the Office SharePoint Usage Processing job to run regularly. Otherwise, the database might not have the data for recent operations.

Comment: this is not a microsoft recommended way. You should not use this approach.